# Combining a list of realtime responses with a list of static responses

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, array

I have written this code that accepts a list of static times and a list of realtime-delayed times.  These are frequently being refreshed and there are times where a train, for example train 23, is scheduled for 2:00PM, so after 2:00PM it leaves the list.

But if it's delayed, I still want it to be a part of the final list (`predictionArray`), which is why I have the boolean flag set the way it is. So basically it compares every static response with every realtime response, and if true, it won't append to `predictionArray` (since all realtime responses are in there already).
Is there a way I could do this maybe without booleans?

Again, I need realtime responses in the `predictionArray` to begin with in case there are any realtime trains that have been added that aren't on the returned static schedule.

```
def coalesceMetraData(staticResponses, realtimeResponses):
    predictionArray = list(realtimeResponses)
    for response in staticResponses:
        responseExists = False
        for responseReal in realtimeResponses:
            if (response['key'] == responseReal['key']):
                responseExists = True
                break
        if (responseExists != True):
            predictionArray.append(response)

    predictionArray = sorted(predictionArray, key=lambda d:d['time'])

    return predictionArray[:5]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are constructing a list out of `realtimeResponses`.

You then iterate over each item in `staticResponses`, and for each static response, you (slowly) look to see if that key is in your list of `realtimeResponses`.

Right there is your room for improvement: a `list` is not the professional data structure of choice for testing if an item is in a collection. For that, you want either a `set` or a `dict`.

In your case, you have extra data in your realtimeResponses, but you don't use it. So `set` seems to be the right choice: put your `realtimeResponses` key values into a set, and then you can just use code like:

```
    realKeys = {rtr['key'] for rtr in realtimeResponses}

    for response in staticResponses:
        if response['key'] in realKeys:
            predictionArray.append(response)
```

Of course, once you have a `for` and an `if` in a tight loop, you can replace it with a *list comprehension*:

```
predictionArray += [resp for resp in staticResponses if resp['key'] in realKeys]
```

Comment: Hi this is a great way of doing it. for realKeys = {...}
inside {} , basically each key was pulled from realtimeResponses and stored into realkeys? so this is a set?
sorry just confused on that syntax a bit!

Comment: Yes. `{onevalue for ...}` is a set comprehension. `{key:value for ...}` is a dict comprehension. See [this article](https://www.smallsurething.com/list-dict-and-set-comprehensions-by-example/) for an introduction to comprehensions and literal syntax.

Answer (score 3):

If I read your code correctly, you start with a list of realtime responses, then conditionally merge in static responses that don't already exist.  A more logical way to express your intention, though, is to start with the list of static responses, then update it with the realtime information, forcibly overwriting in case of collisions.

Note that the latter strategy aligns with the behaviour of the [`dict.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method.  To take advantage of that, though, you should let the `keys` actually be keys of a dictionary.  Also note that dictionaries are designed to perform key lookups quickly — unlike the inefficient linear search for key collisions that you wrote.

With that thinking, the entire function should be implemented in just three statements:

```
from operator import attrgetter

def coalesce_metra_data(static_responses, realtime_responses, first_n=5):
    predictions = {r['key']: r for r in static_responses}
    predictions.update({r['key']: r for r in realtime_responses})
    return sorted(predictions.values(), key=attrgetter('time'))[:first_n]
```

Note that PEP 8, the official Python style guide, recommends [`lower_case_with_underscores`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) for function and variable names.  Also, your `predictionsArray` naming uses a needlessly verbose [Hungarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) suffix.  (In any case, it's actually a list, not an [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html).)

Also, I've chosen to use [`operator.attrgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) as a slightly clearer way to write your lambda that extracts the time attribute.

Consider providing a way to override the hard-coded `5`, as I've done using the optional parameter.  Alternatively, make the caller perform the truncation instead.